# why scala don't allow define lazy val in trait?

Tags: scala

I try to define a trait with a `lazy val`

```
   trait MyTrait {
     lazy val something: Int
   }

   object SomeThing extends MyTrait {
     override lazy val something: Int = 42
   }
```

Then I got compile error in `MyTrait`. I wonder why scala don't allow us define `lazy val` in trait? How can we define `lazy val` in trait?

Comment: You may define _something_ as a `def` and **override** it with a `lazy val`.

Comment: in the trait you just define what the classes that extend it must override. `MyTrait.something` will never be accessed in order to compute the value on call. only `SomeThing.something` is the one that does the calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lazy in a trait does not make sense. `lazy` indicates the calculation of the value only when called.

When you want to access the value of `something` it is not `MyTrait.something` that is going to be called but that property in your classes that extend the trait. In your case 
`SomeThing.something`.

You can keep the `lazy` in your extending classes.

the trait only defines the necessary variables-functions that need to be overridden