# How do I pass an inherited variable into a Auxiliary constructor from a trait

Tags: scala

I'm looking to get the value bork and pass it to a class into the class in the constuctor.

```
trait dog {
  lazy val bork = "bork"
}


class Animal(val firstName: String, dogCommand: DogCommand) extends dog{
  def this(firstName: String) {
    this(firstName, DogCommand(bork))
  }
  
  def getDogCommand(): Unit = {
    dogCommand.getCommand()
  }
}

case class DogCommand(command: String) {
  def getCommand() :Unit = {
      println(command)
  }
}

val myDog = new Animal("first")

myDog.getDogCommand()
```

I usually get - error: not found: value bork

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `bork` is a value on `dog` but there is no instance of `dog` available to read the `bork` from. `this` is a constructor so it doesn't have access to the value that is being constructed.

This is one solution that retains most of the original code:

```
trait dog {
  def bork = dog.DefaultBork
}

object dog {
  val DefaultBork = "bork"
}

class Animal(val firstName: String, dogCommand: DogCommand) extends dog {
  def this(firstName: String) = this(firstName, DogCommand(dog.DefaultBork))

  ...
}
```

You could consider removing the default value of `bork` in `dog` so that any class implementing the trait is required to provide a value for `bork`. (It can always use `DefaultBork` if it wants to retain the default value)

Comment: If the answer is good they you can accept it so that others know this has been answered

Answer (score -1):

For one item, your `this` constructor is incorrect. I also renamed `Dog`.  As for your `lazy val` that wouldn't work on a trait. See more here [why scala don't allow define lazy val in trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461978/why-scala-dont-allow-define-lazy-val-in-trait). Even if you make it non-lazy, that value is not initialized yet until construction when that `val` is not available, yet. Another problem would also be logic, an `Animal` is not `Dog`, but the other way around. Here is an alternative: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WnhxzSn6QtOf5vo1epDDqQ Hope that helps. ;)

```
trait Dog {
  lazy val bork = "bork"
}


class Animal(val firstName: String, dogCommand: DogCommand) extends Dog {
  def this(firstName: String) = this(firstName, DogCommand(bork))
  
  def getDogCommand(): Unit = {
    dogCommand.getCommand()
  }
}

case class DogCommand(command: String) {
  def getCommand() :Unit = {
      println(command)
  }
}

val myDog = new Animal("first")

myDog.getDogCommand()
```

Comment: It would be better to post your solution rather than just reproduce the code in the question.

Comment: @Tim it's their code, but corrected, albeit unsolved

Comment: So it is "corrected" but is still showing the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes. Per my first sentence: "For one item, your `this` constructor is incorrect. I also renamed Dog. As for your `lazy val` that wouldn't work on a trait" ;)

Comment: Also, there is a Scastie link with my answer, with a possibly better approach that does work and is less ceremonious. Not sure you saw that the OPs code arguably violates the OOP "is-a" rule. I made it a link since I felt it wasn't the direct addressing of the OPs code.

Comment: I'm just explaining that your answer does not read well. It is clearer if the code in the answer is correct and it answers the question.